# Join several Optional match querion

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph:

```
CREATE (s1:SOME {id:'s1'} )  
CREATE (s2:SOME {id:'s2'} )
CREATE (a11:ANOTHER {id:'a11', tags:["tag1", "tag2"] } )
CREATE (a12:ANOTHER {id:'a12', tags:["tag2", "tag3"] } )

CREATE (a21:ANOTHER {id:'a21', tags:["tag3", "tag4"] } )
CREATE (a22:ANOTHER {id:'a22', tags:["tag4", "tag5"] } )

CREATE (s1)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a11),
(s1)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a12),
(s2)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a21),
(s2)-[:CONTAINS ]->(a22)
```

I have  ( generated )  query

```
match (s:SOME)

with s 
OPTIONAL MATCH  (a1:ANOTHER)-[r:CONTAINS]-(s)
where 'tag2' in a1.tags

with s, a1
OPTIONAL MATCH  (a2:ANOTHER)-[r:CONTAINS]-(s)
where 'tag3' in a2.tags

WITH s, COLLECT(DISTINCT a1, a2) AS aa

return s.id, aa
```

so there is a lot of sections  like

with s, a1
OPTIONAL MATCH  (a2:ANOTHER)-[r:CONTAINS]-(s)
where 'tag3' in a2.tags

generated dynamically

I have problem with clause

WITH s, COLLECT(DISTINCT a1, a2) AS aa

I need make somehow flatten  this multiple results in single array and distinct it to make it unique

Comment: Do you want a distinct list of a1-a2 pairs, or a list of all distinct a1 and all distinct a2?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to generate any Cypher code for your use case.

The following query takes a `$tags` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/parameters/) -- which should be a list of the tag values you are interested in -- and uses [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) to return each unique `id` and the corresponding list of distinct `a` nodes. The `ANY` function is used to test if any tag in `$tags` is in `a.tags`.

```
MATCH (s:SOME)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:ANOTHER)-[:CONTAINS]-(s)
WHERE ANY(t IN $tags WHERE t in a.tags)
RETURN s.id AS id, COLLECT(DISTINCT a) AS as;
```

Using this query, you just need to generate the `$tags` parameter value.